# "И... в том числе" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> *Любой другой на его месте уже давно бы ненавидел весь мир(,) и медицину в том числе.*

В книге запятая стояла, а мне что-то её не хочется ставить. Понятно, что если написать "в том числе и медицину", то запятая нужна будет, но при таком порядке слов интуиция подсказывает мне поступать по-другому.

Comment: Артем, а какого года книжка?

Comment: @Alex_ander: да прошлого, но я перефразировал первую часть фразы, не уверен, что автор-составитель будет довольна, если я приведу фразу точно и скажу, что за книжка это.

Answer (score 2):

Вот и нестандартная задача.

***В том числе*** считается присоединительным союзом, но я не вижу причин для того, чтобы **в виде исключения** не рассматривать его как обычное наречие.  Союз  И будет тогда соединительным.  Конечно, в большинстве случаев оборот **обособляется**, но это не означает, что он должен обособляться всегда – надо учитывать структуру предложения,  а также контекст.

Здесь возможны **два варианта,** которые различаются ударением и интонацией:

(1) *Любой другой на его месте уже давно бы ненавидел **весь мИр,**  // **и медицину в том числЕ.***

(2) Любой другой на его месте уже давно бы ненавидел **весь мир  и медицину в том числЕ** (= включительно).

Пример без обособления:

*Тема эта, очень ясная лет двадцать назад, когда **любому пионеру и Даше в том числе** **было надёжно извЕстно**, что семейные кухни в скором времени отомрут, домашние очаги погаснут и раскрепощённые женщины будут получать завтраки и обеды на фабриках-кухнях, ― тема эта стала с годами туманной и даже опасной.* [Александр Солженицын, 1990]

Comment: Браво! Не то что Джим со стандартным подходом (так стандартно и я мог себе же ответить :)). *А также контекст тоже* — не поправите? Понятно, что "также" относится к "контексту", а "тоже" к нему же и к "структуре" вместе, но не смущает вас соседство союзов?

Comment: Спасибо, Артем за оценку. А союз, конечно, лишний.

Comment: И вам тоже спасибо за оценку!)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится, так как здесь присоединительные отношения (следовало бы назвать «прибавочные» или «добавочные»). Присоединительные отношения — это когда предложение несет какой-то завершенный смысл, но вносится еще некая добавочная информация. Вот несколько предложений из Розенталя:

> Работу можно было давно уже сделать, и даже лучше.
> Автор статью представил, и своевременно.
> Незаметным образом я привязался к доброму семейству, даже к кривому гарнизонному поручику.

Последнее предложение можно переделать в такое: «Незаметным образом я привязался к доброму семейству, и к кривому гарнизонному поручику в том числе».

[Вот](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_129) еще на Грамоте есть про это.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно отмеченная в одном из ответов нестандартность задачи обусловлена здесь, на мой взгляд, *нестандартностью речи* (т.е. проблема не только с запятой).
С одной стороны, соблюдено минимальное условие для употребления сочетания "в том числе" (предварительно названо *общее понятие*). С другой стороны, по *местоположению* в предложении "в том числе" **не** является *присоединительным союзом* со смыслом "включая", а из этого следует **буквальность** смысла этого сочетания: "*то число*" должно сочетаться с *формой выражения общего понятия* (нужна грамматическая множественность, например, "*всех мировых недоразумений... медицины в том числе*"). Если же трактовать "в том числе" как неделимый штамп (типа наречного выражения или присказки), то с имеющимся общим понятием его не получится связать по смыслу (медицина - "в числе" всего мира?), а это уже граничит с распространившейся *речевой ошибкой* (употребление "в том числе" **вне связи** с обобщающим понятием). Но тогда лучше заменить сочетание "в том числе" на "в частности" (медицина - частный элемент "всего мира"; без запятой перед "и"), либо (убрав "в том числе") вместо союза "и" употребить "*включая*" - тогда через запятую.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр! Мудрёно, но в целом вроде понял. И вроде вы, как всегда, на высоте в своих рассуждениях. ;)

Comment: Alex_ander, но ведь эта речь именно разговорная, а она чаще всего  бывает НЕСТАНДАРТНОЙ.  Она эмоциональна, привязана к конкретности, у нее особый синтаксис и свои задачи. Ваши рассуждения всегда интересны, но они в данном случае хороши для книжной речи. Здесь же они не так актуальны – вариант без обособления встречается РЕДКО, долго думать над ними не приходится. Вот никто и не думает.

Comment: Но вот у Солженицына речь именно книжная. Но там уже сложная структура предложения задает пунктуацию – оборот с обособлением НЕ ВПИСЫВАЕТСЯ в это предложение. Жесткие рамки не всегда хороши, не ко всякому случаю подходят. И тогда начинается конфликт, которым не всем бывает заметен, но художник слова его чувствует хорошо.

Comment: Не хотелось критиковать Солженицына, но к примеру из него мной сказанное тоже относится ("любой пионер" и "в том числе" вне позиции союза рассогласованы). У Розенталя в примерах (их штуки три подряд http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=26#pp26 ) таких вольностей нет.

Comment: Александр, ну вот возьмём тот вариант, что вы предлагаете: "ненавидел бы все мировые недоразумения и медицину в том числе". Поставите запятую или нет?

Comment: Нет, не поставил бы, как и в случае "в частности" на том ж месте.